# How to convert class type in C++ into PyObject type?

Tags: python, c++

I need to embed Python in C++ and I am confused of the class type exchange between Python and C++.

If I have a C++ class as follow:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    void printMessage();
private:
    int m_iVal;
    std::string m_sVal;
};
```

How can I convert the instance of MyClass into PyObject? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the model named ctypes, you can't convert c++ class type to PyObject type, but you can convert c++ structure type to PyObject type which based on a python class named Structure in ctypes model.
[More](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

see 15.17.1.10. Structures and unions.
And there is another way to embed Python use C++, you should use this line `#include <Python.h>` in your c++ program.[More](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html)